# Gradle - export property after copy task finishes

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-task

I have a build pipeline where I want to run a particular jar (with some args) after copying it into a separate folder from the dependency list.

Currently I'm doing the following:

```
task copyToLib(type: Copy, dependsOn: classes) {
    into "$buildDir/server"
    from(configurations.compile) {
        include "webapp-runner*"
    }
    ext.serverPath =  fileTree("$buildDir/server/").include("webapp-runner-*.jar").getSingleFile()
}

task run(type: Exec, dependsOn: [copyToLib, war]) {
    mustRunAfter copyToLib
    executable 'java'
    args '-jar', copyToLib.serverPath, war.archivePath, '--port', "$port"
}
```

But it fails with `Expected directory '...' to contain exactly one file, however, it contains no files.` since I'm guessing `serverPath` is set during config phase when the file has not been copied. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are falling for the common mistake of executing logic in the `configuration` phase when you should be executing it in the `execution` phase.

Try this

```
task copyToLib(type: Copy, dependsOn: classes) {
    ...
    doLast {
        ext.serverPath = ...
    }
}
```

If it were me, I'd calculate `serverPath` inside `run` rather than in `copyToLib`. Perhaps you could use a `closure` to delay the calculation.

Eg:

```
task run(type: Exec, dependsOn: [copyToLib, war]) {
    def pathClosure = {
        fileTree("$buildDir/server/").include("webapp-runner-*.jar").singleFile
    }
    mustRunAfter copyToLib
    executable 'java'
    args '-jar', pathClosure, war.archivePath, '--port', "$port"
}
```

Comment: I tried this but then my run task complains that the property does not exist (probably since `args` runs in configuration phase)

Comment: Error: Unable to access jarfile build_6ya3c8i4opyc4ki50kxakvuxg$_run_closure7$_closure13@61f7c533

Comment: Looks like `args` doesn't support closures (it just calls `toString()` on each arg). You'll need to invoke `project.exec(...)` in a `doLast { ... }` rather than using an `Exec` task. You should raise a ticket on the gradle project for `args` to support `closures`

Comment: Working now with: 
`doLast {
        project.exec({
            commandLine = ['java', '-jar', copyToLib.serverPath(), war.archivePath, '--port', "$port"]
        })
    }`